# Problema com resolução de módulo

Tags: typescript

Estou tentando criar um mapeamento em um projeto que tá sendo executado com o NestJS. Porém ao executar o comando `npm run start:dev` o node retorna o erro `Cannot find module '@entities/user'` no console.

Já realizei diversas pesquisas e não consegui localizar o problema. Alguém consegue me auxiliar? Notei que o comando `npm run start:dev` executa a seguinte instrução: `concurrently --handle-input \"wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon\" \"tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json\"`.

> Arquivo tsconfig.build.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

> Arquivo tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@entities-services/*": ["src/modules/database/services/*"],
      "@entities/*": ["src/entities/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

> Erro retornado

```
module.js:549
[0]     throw err;
[0]     ^
[0]
[0] Error: Cannot find module '@entities/user'
[0]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
[0]     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
[0]     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hiago\Documents\Development\Jewels\api\dist\modules\database\services\user.service.js:18:16)
[0]     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
[0]     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
[0]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[1]
[1] 21:06:08 - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

> Arquivo package.json

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "concurrently --handle-input \"wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon\" \"tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json\" ",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "generate:orm": "node generate-orm.js",
    "typeorm-model-generator": "typeorm-model-generator",
    "prestart:prod": "rimraf dist && npm run build",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.1.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.7",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "supertest": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.2",
    "ts-node": "8.1.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "3.8.0",
    "tslint": "5.16.0",
    "typeorm-model-generator": "^0.3.4",
    "typescript": "3.4.3",
    "wait-on": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: Tu consegue passar o link do repositório por favor? Dessa maneira, posso fazer alguns testes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece por que você está utilizando `path`s customizados, conforme evidenciado na configuração do seu TypeScript:

```
"paths": {
  "@entities-services/*": ["src/modules/database/services/*"],
  "@entities/*": ["src/entities/*"],
  "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"]
}
```

Infelizmente, até o presente momento, o TypeScript não é capaz de resolver isso por si só. Desse modo, se você estiver utilizando Node.js, você deve recorrer à outros módulos.

A solução mais avançada seria usando Webpack em conjunto com o TypeScript, ou Rollup. No entanto, para deixar a resposta mais simples, vamos usar bibliotecas que exigem uma configuração mais simples <s>(só quem trabalhou com Webpack sabe como é chato)</s>.

#### Guia:

Instale a dependência `module-alias`:

```
npm i --save module-alias
```

Adicione o seguinte campo no seu arquivo `package.json`:

```
"_moduleAliases": {
  "@entities-services": "dist/modules/database/services",
  "@entities": "dist/entities",
  "@modules": "dist/modules"],
}
```

E adicione o `import` a seguir no arquivo que é responsável pelo *startup* da aplicação (*entry point*):

```
import 'module-alias/register';
```

#### Referência:

- https://dev.to/lars124/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353

Comment: estava dando erro... Mas a sua resposta me mostrou o caminho. No "_moduleAliases" não precisa dos /* nem dos vetores. Devem ser apenas string's. Pode corrigir que vou colocar como correta.

Answer (score -3):

Update: A simpler way would be to add the *moduleNameMapper* to your json package, then it would be

package.json

```
 "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@entities-services/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../src/modules/database/services/$1",
      "^@entities/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../src/entities/$1",
      "^@modules/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../src/modules/$1"
    }
```

ts.config.json

```
 "paths": {
      "@entities-services/*": ["src/modules/database/services/*"],
      "@entities/*": ["src/entities/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"]
    }
```